# Listagg function get me duplicate data

Tags: oracle, listagg

[image]

The question i want to ask is inside the attachment, please help me out for the solution

Comment: You should delete this question, as it isn't helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found using the SELECT DISTINCT

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/katKV.png]